# Have arrays within arrays in a Swagger responses

Tags: api-design, swagger-2.0

I am trying to define an API in Swagger where the result of a GET is an array of items for model MainModel each with an associated array of items from another model called AnotherModel. Something like this (which does not seem to be allowed):

```
responses:
    200:
      description: search results matching criteria
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/MainModel'
          type: array
          items: $ref: '#/definitions/AnotherModel'
```

Comment: In other words, GET returns an array of `MainModel`, where `MainModel` is an associative array of `AnotherModel`?

Comment: Yes, there will be x items of the AnotherModel associated with every item in the MainModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, OpenAPI Specification supports associative arrays / dictionaries with *string keys* only, such as:

```json
{
  "foo": 5,
  "bar": 2
}
```

but not C#'s `Dictionary<int, string>` where keys are `int`.

An associative array is defined by using an `object` schema with the `additionalProperties` keyword specifying the type of array values. The key type is not mentioned because keys are always strings.

```yaml
type: object
additionalProperties:
  type: <type of array values>
  # OR
  # $ref: '#/definitions/ValueModel'
```

Similarly, an array of associative arrays can be defined as follows:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: <type of values in associative array>
    # OR
    # $ref: '#/definitions/ValueModel'
```

In your example, the values of associative array are of type `AnotherModel`. So an inline definition would look like:

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: search results matching criteria
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              additionalProperties:
                $ref: '#/definitions/AnotherModel'

definitions:
  AnotherModel:
    type: <whatever> # TODO
```

Or if we introduce an intermediate `MainModel` that represents the associative array (as in your original example):

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: search results matching criteria
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/MainModel'

definitions:
  MainModel:  # Associative array of AnotherModel
    type: object
    additionalProperties:
      $ref: '#/definitions/AnotherModel'
  AnotherModel:
    type: <whatever> # TODO
```

A couple of notes:

- Each model referenced via `$ref` must be defined in the `definitions` section. So if you use `$ref: '#/definitions/MainModel'`, your spec must include

  ```yaml
    definitions:
      MainModel:
  ```
- `$ref` works by replacing itself and all its sibling elements with the definition it is pointing at. That's why your original example is not valid:

  ```yaml
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/MainModel'
      type: array
      items: $ref: '#/definitions/AnotherModel'
  ```

  Nested models can be either defined completely inline or referenced via `$ref`, but not both.